# Left Menu keep sub-cateogries open when one selected

Tags: magento-1.9, navigation

I have a left menu which displays on all of my Categroy List and Product Details pages.

I have tweaked it (based on another post in here) so that when a Category is selected the associated sub-categories display also.

What i currently can't get it to do is display the sub-categories when either one of them is selected (it just reverts back to showing the top level categories only) or when a product in one of those sub-categories is being display.

Below is my current code, what tweaks can I make to have the sub-categories main visible for a certain category when the sub-category or product is selected?

```
<?php $_categories = $this->getStoreCategories(); ?>
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>

<div class="block block-layered-nav">
  <div class="block-content">
    <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
      <dd>
        <ol>
          <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
          <?php if ($_category->getIsActive()) : ?>
          <li class="parent"> <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a> <?php echo $_category->getIncludeInMenu() ?> 
            <!-- (<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)-->
            <?php if ($currentCategory && $currentCategory->getId() == $_category->getId()): ?>
            <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
            <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
            <ul>
              <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
              <li class="child"> <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_subcategory)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_subcategory->getName()) ?></a> </li>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </li>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php endforeach ?>
        </ol>
      </dd>
    </dl>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script> 
  </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to update

```
<?php if ($currentCategory && $currentCategory->getId() == $_category->getId()): ?>
```

to

```
$path = explode('/', $_category->getPath());
if ( $currentCategory && in_array($currentCategory->getId(), $path) ) :
```

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately it didn't make any difference, the same thing is still happening

Comment: Did you have any other ideas?